# Ttimezone support in Django-admin for DateTimeField?

Tags: django, timezone, django-admin

We have a Django model Contest:

```py
class Contest(models.Model):
    ...
    time_start = models.DateTimeField()
```

Django `settings.py` has the following TZ settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Server time is set to MSK+03 timezone:

```
$ date
Wed May 29 12:41:14 MSK 2019
```

### What is expected

1. Django stores UTC-datetime in database.
2. When I open object for edit, django-admin converts UTC-datetime from database to my local computer timezone, which is already stored in my django session.
3. And vice versa, when I save object with date, it's converted from my local computer TZ, entered in django admin, to UTC and stored in database.

### What I got

1. Instead of converting received datetime to UTC, Django just corrects it with `TIME_ZONE` offset and saves to DB. It doesn't matter, which TZ is used on my local computed — US/RU/etc. It always subtracts -03 hours as 'Europe/Moscow' offset is +03, and saved the result to DB.
2. When I change TZ on my local computer and re-login to django-admin, object datetime is not corrected to respect my current client TZ, but always stays the same despite I use different timezones.

So, how it supposed to work?

DB

```
MariaDB> describe contest;
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| time_start       | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Django version:

```
>>> django.__version__
'2.2.1'
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is working as expected, and as described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/). See [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) in particular: "There’s no equivalent of the `Accept-Language` HTTP header that Django could use to determine the user’s time zone automatically. Instead, Django provides time zone selection functions. Use them to build the time zone selection logic that makes sense for you."

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thank you. Maybe I'm missing something, but I've read this section and tried timezone middleware before posting question. `django_timezone` does not exist in request.session when processing django-admin requests.

Comment: Maybe it supposed to be built in real-time, based on user IP in middleware?

Comment: What timezone middleware did you try? The code in the documentation is just an incomplete "example", you have to implement it yourself. If you did so, you need to include that implementation in your question.

Comment: It's up to you. Again, there's no standard, so Django itself doesn't handle it. There are third-party packages, like [django-tz-detect](https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect), that provide support for this. (Note [this issue](https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect/issues/36) about using IP addresses.)

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Ah, I see. It was a bit unexpected for me this problem has no default out-of-box solution. I'll try several options and post answer which I'd end up with. Thank you.